# Nested query SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a quote_item table where each item has the following fields: name, product_id, r_code1, r_code2

Product table also has r_code1 and r_code2

That data is in two locations because the user wanted quotes to be a snapshot, if they change r_code1 later at the product level it shouldn't impact quotes automatically.

However I've now been asked to reflect r_code changes to existing quotes since there was a mistake.

If I have a quote with 20 quote_items, how would I write a query that updates each quote_item.rcode_1 to the corresponding product.rcode_1. The link is through quote_item.product_id = product.id.

Thanks in advance
Nick

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: postgres, sorry to leave that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is standard SQL that would work in any database:

```
update qi
    set rcode_1 = (select p.rcode_1 from product p where p.id = qi.product_id);
```

There are other ways to express this, depending on the database, but the above should work in any database.

Answer (score 2):

```
update qi set qi.rcode_1 = product.rcode_1 
from quote_items qi
    inner join product 
        on product.id = qi.product_id
```